# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class

Tags: java

I am getting this error while generating the signed apk.Even i tried many solutions but no one is works for me.

Please Help me:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class
```

and my gradle file code is

Build.gradle is here please tell me what is my error for generating signed apk:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "MyKey", onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.8.3, 3.99.99]'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your one of dependency has different version of android support library.force the version in build.gradle root with

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
        force 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    }
}
```